# Express server putting out wrong value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an array with elements and I want to compare the URL input to it.

For example when a user inputs `localhost:8080/ingredients/raisins` I want to return `In Stock` and if it's something that's not inside the array (eg. `/ingredients/chicken`), it should be `Out of Stock`.

However, for the time being it just returns `Out of Stock`, no matter the user's input. What am I missing here?

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const ingredients = ["Raisins", "Pepper", "Beef"];

app.get("/ingredients/:ingredient", (req, res) => {
  const { ingredient } = req.params;
  const foundIngredient = ingredients.find((item) => item === ingredient);

  if (foundIngredient) {
    res.send("In Stock!");
  } else {
    res.send("Out of Stock!");
  }
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log("I am running on port 8080");
});
```

Comment: `'raisins'` !== `'Raisins'`.

Comment: @Dazil What if there's more than one `params`? Preferably put `toString` inside the `find` function if you think that's a concern. Params are always stringified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have some error on the capitalize word , try to standardize the word before comparing. You can try to compare all with lower case .
Or as @Joel said you can use "localCompare"  this to better performance comparing

```
const foundIngredient = ingredients.some((item) =>item.localeCompare(ingredient, "en", { sensitivity: "base" }));

if (foundIngredient) {
 res.send("In Stock!");
} else {
 res.send("Out of Stock!");
}
```

And also as improve not use `find()`, because you are looking for a boolean, not a entity,so you can use `some()` instead, take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) how to use it

Comment: Don't use `.toLowerCase()` when comparing strings, it's very inefficient and doesn't cover all cases. Use `str1.localeCompare(str2, "en", { sensitivity: "base" })` instead.

Comment: Agree, this is better comparing method @timohuennebeck

Comment: Haven't heard of some() or localeCompare() before but will def. have a look into it. Thanks for the help folks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// Make sure that all ingredients are always lowercase, this way you will avoid accidental mis-configuration.
const ingredients = ["Raisins", "Pepper", "Beef"].map((v) => v.toLowerCase());

app.get("/ingredients/:ingredient", (req, res) => {
  const { ingredient } = req.params;

  // Using `includes` is a shorter version of `arr.some((v) => v === ingredient)
  // Before checking for user-input existence, transform it to lowercase as well, so we can match no matter the casing.
  const foundIngredient = ingredients.includes(ingredient.toLowerCase());

  res.send(foundIngredient ? "In Stock!" : "Out of Stock!");
});

app.listen(8080, () => console.log("I am running on port 8080"));
```